# How to copy a forum thread?

Tags: 7, nodes

I want to move a forum thread with all the posts from one server to another. What is the most convenient way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Bundle Copy](https://drupal.org/project/bundle_copy) Module...

> Has export/import support for:
>
> - Node types
> - Taxonomy
> - User
> - Field API fields
> - Field groups
>
> You can find the export/import links for the supported entities on
>   following paths:
>
> - Nodes: admin/structure/types
> - Taxonomy: admin/structure/taxonomy
> - Users: admin/config/people/accounts

Comment: This module lacks README.txt. I could not figure out how to use it.

Comment: Documentation goes here..https://drupal.org/node/1982368